# Why do hindus need to worship more gods?

Tags: gods

If it is believed that only Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva are the supreme gods, why do we worship other gods like Rama, Krishna, Sai baba etc

These days some people are saying that Sai baba is not a god, and some people are saying he is incarnation of Lord Shiva so instead of worshipping Sai, it is better to worship only Lord Shiva right?

I mean anyway as Sai is incarnation of Lord Shiva, if one worships only Lord Shiva, it reaches to Lord Sai baba also, am I wrong?

My question is if a person worships a human being believing(wrongly) him to be some god's incarnation, then he wont get mukti or moksha right?

I like all gods either sai baba or even others

Comment: It may sound worded better if the word "need" is removed? And capital W on why.

Comment: sir, suppose God comes and takes birth as your son. Won't you have that connection with Him. Similarly Lord Vishnu is God. But He is in Vaikunta and seems inaccesible to most mortals. But when He takes incarnation as Sri Krishna. THen now He is a human being and is more accessible to us. That is why people worship avatars.

Comment: Just as all devotees believe that Sri Krishna is the human incarnation of Sri Vishnu. The SaiBaba devotees believe that Lord Sai is the incarnation of Lord Vishnu (or Lord Shiva). The Gaudiya Vaishnavas belive Lord Chaitanya is an incarnation. The Sri Vaishnavas believe Ramanuja is an incarnation. The Ramakrishna mission members believe that Sri Ramakrishna is an incarnation. Thus each one has the right to believe in His faith so long as He does not harm others faith sir.

Comment: @Sai - It is sad to see that you are categorising saibaba as one among gods or great Realised souls. No great realised souls or genuine acharyas will ever say that they are god. Atleast there are genuine references for genuine acharyas in genuine hindu scriptures. There is no references for Sai baba even as a genuine guru.. Faith is altogether different matter but ill conceived faith is more dangerous.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to delete your question?

Comment: Bcoz every single God and the experiences of the bhaktas gives you bliss of God. And one needs to start from the bottom, not all can reach the highest so you have to start from the small deities, or demigods in order to reach to the highest.

Comment: "**If it is believed that only Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva are the supreme gods, why do we worship other gods like Rama, Krishna, Sai baba etc**"- No. Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva are not ***"only"*** supreme God. Krishna, Rama, Ganesha , Kaartikeya, Devi MahaShakti, MahaLakshmi, MahaSaraswati, Shri Hanumaan, Bhairava, Agni...... all are Supreme God. There is no question of "***only***". All Gods are in fact one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People wonder why Hindus worship many Gods! Vedas and later Vedanta clearly talks about one God without a second. They call it as Brahman. Then, what is the point of praying to multiple deities? Hindus worship many Gods because they know that many Gods are the manifestations of single God - the one without a second (Ekamevadityiam).

> Rig Veda I. 164. 46
>
> "Ekam sad vipra bahudha vadanti."
>
> Though it is one, inspired poets speak of it in many ways (or, The poets give many names to that which is only one).

From the ancient time, Hindus value the pluralistic outlook. It is one of the core features of Hindu religion.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I am getting some doubts to clarify from you, if the god is brahman then whom did sages worshipped. The gods mentioned in our puranas, ramayanam, bhaaratham etc are not real and did they not happen on earth? Sorry if any thing wrong

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23759/which-verses-in-vedas-and-upanishads-can-be-used-to-prove-that-brahman-is-saguna/23774#23774

Comment: Read my answer on the above link. You will understand. In short, this material world is the dream of supreme consciousness. Our consciousness is not different from that. We are instances of that consciousness. Puranas and Epics are just stories. There is no God as such. The only one God Vedanta talks about is Brahman, which is Satchidananda. (Sad truth, chit means consciousness and anada means bliss)  That alone exists.

Comment: Worshipping is nothing but trying to realize that truth. The only valid path is the path of knowldege. Because by knowing only we can realize anything. Nanyo pantha vidhiyate hayanay. (isha Upanishad). There is no other path than this path. Idols, worship is just a stepping stone.

Comment: If you want to know in details, read this resources. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22476/resources-to-learn-about-hinduism-for-an-ex-muslim-who-has-been-agnostic-for-abo/23812#23812

Comment: From your comments, is it like 'ramayanam', 'mahabharatham', 'bagavad gita' etc, we wrote for ourselves? What is the need for a person to do good to others if all those are just myths and not true... If a person not fear of god means there is nothing for him to do good to others in my opinition...

Comment: Also I know some details about Advaitha as mentioned by Adi Shankara 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara

Answer (score 7):

Its the choice given to people. You can choose a deity of your choice and worship him. Its just as simple as that. Swami Virajeshwara (http://www.swami-virajeshwara.com/)  says that any deity worshipped with immense bhakti yields results.

Then why do have so many gods? Let me try to explain with an example.
Person X likes Jalebi, Y likes Burfi and Z likes Jamoon. Now the contents of all sweets are almost same(sugar,powder,elaichi etc.) Just the process is different. Similarly your taste and my taste differs in all the aspects including spirituality & religion. I might like Lord Krishna whereas you might like Lord Ganesha. At the end all are same. But the process of worship and attaining bhakti is different. That is the beauty of Hinduism. No one forces you to follow one person or one God. You are free to create your own god. At the end, it just merges to one single God.

Comment: and that single God is the Nirguna Brahman of Advaita Vedanta.

Comment: Also Sai baba says Sabka malik ek.(one god different names) That means what ever we pray do worship it is for better environment and attain moksh. That is all about nature.

Comment: Different flavors of the ice cream